# Spring - Set autowired object in another class for junit tests

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit, factory

I have a class Controller:
Question is in the comments of Test class-  how should I mock myFactory object and set this object as a property of controller? Even if I mock the factory object using @Mock/ EasyMock, how should I set this in controller as with Autowiring, it does not have the setter for factory
            So, I cant use controller.setFactory()
            Also, How do I mock the methods in factory object , the way I do it for objects with @Mock : Mockito.when(factory.someFactoryMethod).andReturn("abc")

```
public class Controller{
    @Autowired
    MyFactory factory;

    someMethod(){
        String abh = factory.someFactoryMethod("defaultObject");
    }
}

public class MyFactory{
    public String someFactoryMethod(String argument){
        //some code
    }
}


public class ControllerTest{
    @Before
    public void initialize() {
       Controller testController = spy(new Controller());
           /*
        how should I mock myFactory object and set this object as a property of controller? Even if I mock the factory object using @Mock/ EasyMock, how should I set this in controller as with Autowiring, it does not have the setter for factory
        So, I cant use controller.setFactory(<mocked object>)
        Also, How do I mock the methods in factory object , the way I do it for objects with @Mock : Mockito.when(factory.someFactoryMethod).andReturn("abc") 
        */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest at least autowiring on constructor lvl:

```
private final MyFactory factory;

@Autowired
public Controller(MyFactory factory) {
  this.factory = factory;
}
```

Than in tests you can mock (via Mockito or create your own) or pass a concrete instance to the Controller:

```
@Before
public void initialize() {
  private Controller testController = new Controller(factory);
}
```

To mock factory and use the `given` you specified you can mock it like that:

```
MyFactory factory = Mockito.mock(MyFactory.class);
```

EDIT (using annotations)
This test class could also be an example for you for using annotation based mocking from Mockito: https://github.com/gmaslowski/spock-groovy-sample/blob/master/src/test/java/com/gmaslowski/spock/sample/DummyServiceTest.java

Answer (score -1):

You could use `@InjectMocks` in conjunction with `@Spy`

```
public class ControllerTest{
    @Mock
    MyFactory factory;

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    Controller testController;

    @Before
    public void initialize() {
        //expectations
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to invoke `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` ?